# Product of two complex numbers in less than 3 multiplications

Tags: algorithm, multiplication, discrete-mathematics, strassen, karatsuba

Can someone break this down for me? Why can't it be done in two multiplications?

**The Multiplication of Complex Numbers**

If the number of multiplications required for a computation is regarded as a measure of its difficulty and these computations are performed using complex numbers, it is natural to ask how many real multiplications are necessary to
evaluate the real and imaginary parts of a complex product. The natural
way of forming a complex product requires four real multiplications.
It may, however, be done in three but not in two multiplications.

```
(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac-bd) + (ad+bc)i

a(c+d) - d(a+b) = ac - bd
 (1)      (2)

a(c+d) + c(b-a) = ad + bc
          (3)
```

**Theorem** - The evaluation of the product of two complex numbers requires three real multiplications, even if multiplication by real constants is not counted.

**Sketch of proof** Since neither the real nor the complex part of a complex multiplication can be determined in one real multiplication , if this calculation can be done in two multiplications it will be done, for some choice of C<sub>i</sub>, W<sub>i</sub>, X<sub>i</sub>, Y<sub>i</sub> and Z<sub>i</sub> in the following manner.

```
ac - bd = C₁(W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d)
            (W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d)
        + C₂(W₃a+X₃b+Y₃c+Z₃d)
            (W₄a+X₄b+Y₄c+Z₄d)
ad + bc = C₃(W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d)
            (W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d)
        + C₄(W₃a+X₃b+Y₃c+Z₃d)
            (W₄a+X₄b+Y₄c+Z₄d)
```

This leads to 20 non-linear equations in the 20 unknowns, C<sub>i</sub>, W<sub>i</sub>, X<sub>i</sub>, Y<sub>i</sub> and Z<sub>i</sub> where (i = 1,2,3,4), which have no real solution and hence there is no way to perform a complex multiplication in two real multiplications

*Source:*

Munro, Ian. "40-44." http://dl.acm.org/. Proc. of Proceedings of the Third Annual ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing, Ohio, Shaker Heights. Ed. Michael A. Harrison, Ranan B. Banerji, and Jeffrey D. Ullman. Acm, 03 May 1971. Web. 26 Nov. 2016. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=800157.805036.

Comment: Could you cite the source of this quotation? Also, could you set off the quotation with '>', so that it's clear that it's a quotation?

Comment: It is about programming. The karatsuba algorithm in particular. @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: @ruakh I just cited.

Answer (score 1):

So, the theorem being proved here is basically, "Even if you can do as many additions, subtractions, and multiplications-by-predetermined-constants as you like, you can't compute *ac−bd* and *ad+bc* without doing at least three multiplications-of-two-*non*-predetermined-quantities."

(Note: henceforth, I will abbreviate "multiplication(s) of two non-predetermined quantities" as "MNPQ(s)".)

The proof begins by pointing out that you certainly can't compute either one of { *ac−bd*, *ad+bc* } with just a single MNPQ. So the only way you could compute *both* of them with just *two* MNPQs would be if you can somehow "share" those MNPQs, using both of their results in both of { *ac−bd*, *ad+bc* }.

The proof relies on the unstated premise, by the way, that if all you've got are additions, subtractions, and multiplications-by-predetermined-constants, then ultimately anything you do will just amount to a linear combination of your inputs. (Do you see why?) So the two MNPQs will both be multiplications of linear combinations of { *a*, *b*, *c*, *d* }, and the way that you "share" their results will be for { *ac−bd*, *ad+bc* } to be two different linear combinations of the results of those MNPQs. (A *complete* proof would require a more thorough argument regarding the possibility that the result of one MNPQ might be an argument to the other, as well as the possibility that the final linear combinations incorporate not just the results of the MNPQs but also { *a*, *b*, *c*, *d* }; but this is labeled just "sketch of proof", so I guess it doesn't have to worry about such things.)

If you accept that premise, then we can write the two MNPQs as (W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d)·(W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d) and (W₃a+X₃b+Y₃c+Z₃d)·(W₄a+X₄b+Y₄c+Z₄d), and their two linear combinations (*ac−bd* and *ad+bc*) as C₁(MNPQ)₁+C₂(MNPQ)₂ and C₃(MNPQ)₃+C₄(MNPQ)₄. If you then multiply everything through, you get a system of equations to solve — the unknowns to solve for being the magical constants W₁, X₂, C₃, etc. — except that, as it turns out, this system of equations actually has no solution. Therefore, no set of magical constants will enable this approach, therefore this approach is impossible, therefore you need to perform at least three MNPQs in order to compute both *ac−bd* and *ad+bc*.

Comment: How is (W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d)·(W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d)  one multiplication? There are magical constants in each parenthesis that need to be computed and are not predetermined.

Comment: @SuperCell: I'm not sure why you think that. In fact, that's a contradiction in terms: the definition of a "constant" is that it *is* predetermined. (W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d) and (W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d) are just two specific linear combinations of { *a*, *b*, *c*, *d* }.

Comment: I am saying the magical constants need to be multiplied by a b c d respectively.

Comment: @SuperCell: Yes, but that is specifically allowed, as I noted in the first paragraph of this answer. (As Munro puts it, "multiplication by real constants is not counted".)

Comment: Alright fair but how does that prove it can't be done with two multiplications?

Comment: @SuperCell: If all you can do is addition, subtraction, multiplication by predetermined constants, and *two* multiplications of non-predetermined quantities, then your result will necessarily take the form C₁(W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d)·(W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d) + C₂(W₃a+X₃b+Y₃c+Z₃d)·(W₄a+X₄b+Y₄c+Z₄d). So we have the equations ac-bd = C₁(W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d)·(W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d) + C₂(W₃a+X₃b+Y₃c+Z₃d)·(W₄a+X₄b+Y₄c+Z₄d) and ad+bc = C₃(W₁a+X₁b+Y₁c+Z₁d)·(W₂a+X₂b+Y₂c+Z₂d) + C₄(W₃a+X₃b+Y₃c+Z₃d)·(W₄a+X₄b+Y₄c+Z₄d), which must be true for *all* a, b, c, and d. Which, by straightforward (but tedious) algebra, is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is by contradiction.

Assume that we can evaluate the multiplication of two complex number by 2 real multiplications, then you are required to evaluate ***ac-bd*** and ***ad+bc*** using 2 multiplications.

It should have the manner posted by you where both evaluations consist of the exactly same two multiplications with different real constant coefficients ***C1, C2, C3, C4*** where ***Xi, Yi, Zi, Wi*** should be real numbers as well.

Since the coefficients of *a^2, b^2, c^2, d^2, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd* should match in the two equations, we have 20 non-linear equations with 20 unknowns. For example, **C1*W1*W2 + C2*W3*W4 = 0** for *a^2* in the first evaluation of ***ac-bd***. This proof further claims that the system does not have real solutions and therefore the assumption does not hold.

Comment: Why incorporate C coefficients? and why multiply a b c d with x y z w? Also how is that 2 multiplications? Wouldn't C1(W1a+X1b+Y1c+Z1d ) (W2a+X2b+Y2c+Z2d) be 25 multiplications?

Comment: Like what @ruakh said, the statement itself declare that multiply a,b,c,d with constant does not count as a multiplication. Only the multiplication in between a,b,c,d are considered as multiplications. Ci and Xi, Yi, Zi, Wi are put in because you want to somehow arrange a,b,c,d so that you can get exactly ac-bd and ad+bc like the example shown for 3 multiplications.